# SQLite UPDATE record syntax in Poco

Tags: sqlite, syntax, sql-update, poco-libraries

I can't get the syntax here; are there some more extensive examples for POCO-SQLite ?

I am getting a Poco::exception, 
sendErrorResponse HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

```
                    Poco::Data::SQLite::Connector::registerConnector();
                    // create a new session
                    Session updsession("SQLite", managers);
                    facilities UnitFacility;

                    Statement updateRecord(updsession);

                    updsession << "UPDATE facilities SET name = nameString, address = addressString, phone = phoneString WHERE facilityNumber = 3;";
                    updateRecord.execute();
```

//Updated: Simplified   With or without []  still no go.

```
                    Poco::Data::SQLite::Connector::registerConnector();
                    Session updsession("SQLite", managers);
                    Statement updateRecord(updsession);
                    updsession << "UPDATE facilities SET Name = 'Frank' WHERE [FacilityNumber = 1];",now;
                    updateRecord.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Both SQL queries are invalid.

Original Query:

```
UPDATE facilities SET name = nameString, address = addressString, phone = phoneString WHERE facilityNumber = 3
```

Result:

```
no such column: nameString: UPDATE facilities SET name = nameString, address = addressString, phone = phoneString WHERE facilityNumber = 3
```

Fixed query:

```
UPDATE facilities SET name = 'nameString', address = 'addressString', phone = 'phoneString' WHERE facilityNumber = 3
```

Result:

```
Query executed successfully: UPDATE facilities SET name = 'nameString', address = 'addressString', phone = 'phoneString' WHERE facilityNumber = 3 (took 0ms, 1 rows affected)
```

Original query:

```
UPDATE facilities SET Name = 'Frank' WHERE [FacilityNumber = 1]
```

Result:

```
no such column: FacilityNumber = 1: UPDATE facilities SET Name = 'Frank' WHERE [FacilityNumber = 1]
```

Fixed query:

```
UPDATE facilities SET Name = 'Frank' WHERE FacilityNumber = 1
```

Result:

```
Query executed successfully: UPDATE facilities SET Name = 'Frank' WHERE FacilityNumber = 1 (took 0ms, 1 rows affected)
```

It is not clear what does this question have to do with HTTP.

Comment: I started with a HTTP server, that's what we are.
:)


How do you pass parameters ?...

nameString is the string with data, how can I pass that ?
thanks for the help :)

Comment: Should I use a different type of server structure ? Not HTTP ?

Comment: its still stuck at line 96, HTTPServerConnection.cpp
.. using  

                    updsession << "UPDATE facilities SET Name = 'Tom' WHERE FacilityNumber = 3",now;
                    updateRecord.execute();   //<-- this works !  but still throws the exception.